# Cannot VBoxManage ModifyVM --nataliasmode1 when running

Tags: nat, virtualbox

I tried to run modifyvm

```
PS C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox> ./vboxmanage modifyvm XXX --nataliasmode1 proxyonly
VBoxManage.exe: error: The machine 'XXX' is already locked for a session (or being unlocked)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_INVALID_OBJECT_STATE (0x80bb0007), component Machine, interface IMachine, callee IUnknown
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "LockMachine(a->session, LockType_Write)" at line 471 of file VBoxManageModifyVM.cpp
```

but it shows already locked for a session, is there any GUI way to update the NAT Alias Mode?

Comment: Maybe adding another network interface will work?